# ¿Cómo traducir este código a Visual Basic.net?

Tags: c#

Soy programador novato en Visual Basic y necesito traducir este pedacito de código de C# a VB pero no logro entenderlo bien, básicamente porque no entiendo lo de los invoke y los delegados, unido al uso de una expresión lambda. ¿Podeis ayudarme a traducir la linea en negrita a VB? ¡GRACIAS!

```
do
{
    if (_worker2.CancellationPending)
        break;
    **textBox_buffer_size.Invoke((Action)delegate**
    {
        textBox_buffer_size.Text = controlador.queue.Count.ToString();
    });

} while (true);
```

Comment: No elimines partes esenciales de tu pregunta.